# Which Sharepoint 2007 development book is most dedicated to client-side programming?

Tags: 2007, books

I need to learn how to develop web pages in Sharepoint 2007, so I'm looking for a book.  However, I only have client-side access, and it's not clear which of the SP2007 developer textbooks concentrate on client-side programming.

I've read the reviews for:

- Pro SharePoint Solution Development: Combining .NET, SharePoint and
  Office 2007
- Professional SharePoint 2007 Development
- MicrosoftSharePoint 2007 Development Unleashed
- Microsoft® Office SharePoint®
  Designer 2007 Step by Step

Are any of these books especially good for client-side development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008W3A1Q0) has a chapter devoted to Ajax and client-side programming.

Comment: I'll give this one a try.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Client-side programming wasn't really a big part of SharePoint 2007. No API's, no "javascript-way" of doing things. It wasn't until SharePoint 2010 it really started becoming a thing in SharePoint.

So I'm afraid it's a bit of a Mission Impossible to try and find books about client-side programming for SharePoint 2007.

Comment: To add to Daniel's answer: Most of the client-side stuff I have come across for 2007 used the SOAP web services, might be worth investigating but I'm not super familiar with them myself.

Comment: Yes, I've been learning about how to use the web services to simplify SOAP packet construction, and how to build my own Javascript API for this sort of thing.  I've found some info on MSDN but was hoping that someone had already written a textbook on it.

Comment: I'd have a look at SPServices from Marc Anderson: http://spservices.codeplex.com/